# Should the development and programming tags be merged?

Tags: discussion

The [development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/development) and [programming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/programming) tags seem very similar.  Sometimes it's obvious that a development question isn't strictly about programming, but otherwise, they overlap.

As a user, I'm not sure when I would search through one or the other.  Maybe make programming be a synonym for development?

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: I agree as well. In theory, they both have a different meaning; One is "How to program on Ubuntu", the other is related to the development of Ubuntu itself, in reality however, people use them interchangeably (and it's not obvious which is which).

Comment: Right, but that's not our fault, Ubuntu the project has always called "Development" something different than what people think it should be, so if people are going to mix it up let's just combine it and the "ubuntu developer as in packaging" can go under packaging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Nothing to add to Michael rational, he is just right, both tags have a very similar scope.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if the tags were seperated more - almost like programming being a beginners section and development being more technical?